# How to make sure that only one of two fields are populated in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, model

I am using mongoose as an ODM and trying to model an animal/pet. In the model I have 2 fields, parent and shelter. I want to make sure that pet belongs to a person or a shelter but not both. What constraints would allow me to do this.

My model in JS:-

```
const petSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Pet must have a name."],
        trim: true
    },
    species: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Pet must have a species."]
    },
    parent: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    shelter: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Shelter'
    }
}
```

I am new to databases and their jargons, correct me if any error in question.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using pre validate middleware in mongoose:-

```
petSchema.pre('validate', function (next) {
    if((this.parent && this.shelter) || (!this.parent && !this.shelter))
        return next(new Error("At least and Only one field(parent, shelter) should be populated"))
    next()
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the required function to determine this as follows:

```
const petSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Pet must have a name."],
        trim: true
    },
    species: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Pet must have a species."]
    },
    parent: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: function() {
          return !this.shelter;
        }
    },
    shelter: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Shelter',
        required: function() {
          return !this.parent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not raise an error(when I pass in both parent and a shelter), but when I put the same function in validate it does. But, problem with that is when I populate neither of them, it accepts it.

Comment: ah I misunderstood you also wanted to validate that. you can use the following:

`
validate: {
  validator: function(v) {
    // add your validation here 
  }
}
`

You can use condition inside of the validator function that will allow you the flexibility you want